# Ethernet connection very slow in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Desktop) and OpenSUSE Leap 15.3 (Desktop)

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet, ubuntu-drivers

I have problems with my Dell Latitude 5420. My internet connection works fine in Windows 10, but when I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Desktop) or OpenSUSE Leap 15.3 (Desktop), my connection works fine with Wi-Fi, but not with Ethernet.

- I have 2 or 5 Mb/s download speed with Ethernet and 100 Mb/s with Wi-Fi.
- I have 200 Mb/s upload speed with Ethernet and 100 Mb/s with Wi-Fi.

As you can see, with Ethernet uploading works fine, but not downloading.

**Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Desktop) information:**

**Here my network hardware (I have an Intel i5 10th generation x64 bits as a processor):**

```
*-network:0               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlp0s20f3
   version: 20
   serial: 94:e2:3c:2e:4d:20
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-36-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.86.35 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6055294000-6055297fff

*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 20
   serial: 38:14:28:54:e1:03
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-36-generic firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:164 memory:a6100000-a611ffff
```

**Relese version:**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and- 
policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

**Kernel version:**

```
5.11.0-37-generic
```

**OpenSUSE Leap 15.3 (Desktop) information:**

**Here my network hardware (I have an Intel i5 10th generation x64 bits as a processor):**

```
*-network:0
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlan1
   version: 20
   serial: 94:e2:3c:29:85:b5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.18-59.24-default firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6053194000-6053197fff

*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: eth2
   version: 20
   serial: 38:14:28:54:da:d7
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:158 memory:a2300000-a231ffff
```

**Relese version:**

```
NAME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="15.3"
ID="opensuse-leap"
ID_LIKE="suse opensuse"
VERSION_ID="15.3"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Leap 15.3"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:leap:15.3"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
```

**Kernel version:**

```
5.3.18-59.24-default
```

Can you help me solve this issue on my Dell Latitude 5420?

**FYI:** I've seen the width of the ethernet connection and it's 32 bits instead of 64 bits and I don't know because this happens. The only thing that got my attention is the driver, which is e1000e. My guess is that the system is using this generic driver because it can't find anything else. It seems that is the NIC. I've seen the DELL [page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-gd/product-support/product/latitude-5420-laptop/drivers) to download drivers for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and only appears the DRIVER to update the BIOS.

I hope somebody can help me. Many thanks!

Comment: The OpenSUSE is off-topic here though it may provide extra facts if you provided what kernel was being used there (if we're not opensuse leap users), also what stack choice you've made with your *unstated* Ubuntu 20.04 LTS product (server? desktop? which stack choice you used..), and whether or not you've tried both choices (ie. GA & HWE; given they are pretty easy to install, test & remove if unhelpful generally).

Comment: This seems to be [a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1927925) with a fix coming in Kernel 5.15. There are some patches available to make it work with earlier kernels (See [response 93](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1927925/comments/93)) depending on your level of comfort working in the command line 

Comment: Many thanks for your comments! I edited the question and I added the version of kernel in each OS. I use both in Desktop way. I don't tried to update the kernel, I'm using the deafult kernel of the system as you can see. So, in the kernel version 5.15 this will be solved? You know when I will can to install it in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? What is the last stable version for the kernel? @matigo